# How to get original value after applying scale()?

Tags: r, scale

How can you get the original values after applying `scale()` to a vector?

```
x <- c(11, 12, 13,24, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19)

scaled <- scale(x)
```

Comment: Unless you saved the mean and SD of x there is no way.

Comment: @user2974951 mean and SD are saved in the returned object.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `attributes`

```
x <- c(11, 12, 13,24, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19)

y <- scale(x)
z <- attributes(y)
    
y * (z$'scaled:scale') + z$'scaled:center'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `unscale` function from the `DMwR` package:

```
remotes::install_github("cran/DMwR")
library(DMwR)
x <- c(11, 12, 13,24, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19)
scaled <- scale(x)
original <- unscale(scaled, scaled)
```

Output:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]   11
 [2,]   12
 [3,]   13
 [4,]   24
 [5,]   25
 [6,]   16
 [7,]   17
 [8,]   18
 [9,]   19
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, calculate the mean and SD of x beforehand

```
x <- c(11, 12, 13,24, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19)

scaled <- scale(x)
m <- mean(x)
sd <- sd(x)
unscaled <- scaled*sd + m
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `attributes` from `scaled` within the `scale` function itself:

```r
x <- c(11, 12, 13,24, 25, 16, 17, 18, 19)

scaled <- scale(x)

x <- scale(scaled,
           center = -attr(scaled,"scaled:center")/attr(scaled,"scaled:scale"),
           scale = 1/attr(scaled,"scaled:scale")
           )

x
```

**Output:**

```r
> x
      [,1]
 [1,]   11
 [2,]   12
 [3,]   13
 [4,]   24
 [5,]   25
 [6,]   16
 [7,]   17
 [8,]   18
 [9,]   19
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] -3.483366
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 0.20226
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
as.numeric(scaled) * attr(scaled , "scaled:scale") 
                   + attr(scaled , "scaled:center")
```